# Spark ML Naive Bayes predict multiple classes with probabilities

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

Is there a way to let the model to return a list of prediction labels with the probability score for each label?

For example
given feature (f1,f2,f3),
it returns something like this:
label1:0.50,label2:0.33...

Is it doable in spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
The output from `rawPrediction` column is an `Array[Double]` which contains the probability for each label.

In your example this column would be an Array(0.5,0.33,0.17), you will have to write an UDF that transforms this Array into a String.

It is important to note that if you used a StringIndexer to encode your label column the resulting labels will be different from your original ones. [(most frequent label gets index 0)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer)

Had some code that does something similar which can be adapted to your use case.
My code just writes the top X predictions for each feature as a CSV file.
parameter @df for writeToCsv must be a DataFrame after it has been transformed by your Naive Bayes model.

```
 def topXPredictions(v: Vector, labels: Broadcast[Array[String]], topX: Int): Array[String] = {
    val labelVal = labels.value
    v.toArray
      .zip(labelVal)
      .sortBy {
        case (score, label) => score
      }
      .reverse
      .map {
        case (score, label) => label
      }
      .take(topX)
  }

  def writeToCsv(df: DataFrame, labelsBroadcast: Broadcast[Array[String]], name: String = "output"): Unit = {
    val get_top_predictions = udf((v: Vector, x: Int) => topXPredictions(v, labelsBroadcast, x))

      df
      .select(
        col("id")
        ,concat_ws(" ", get_top_predictions(col("rawPrediction"), lit(10))).alias("top10Predictions")
       )
      .orderBy("id")
      .coalesce(1)
      .write
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .save(name)
  }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Thanks a lot!